# SQLite and knex - delete CASCADE

Tags: node.js, database, sqlite, database-migration, knex.js

I have a little problem on delete datas on my database.

I'm doing a app to create notes for movies (rating, comments, etc.) and I'm using two ways to set my database:

I created the table "users" manully using node and migrations:

```js
const createUsers = `
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR,
    email VARCHAR,
    password VARCHAR,
    avatar VARCHAR NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  )
`

module.exports = createUsers;
```

And I created the tables 'movie_notes' and 'movie_tags' using the library 'knex' with migrations

```js
exports.up = knex => knex.schema.createTable("movie_notes", table => {
  table.increments("id");
  table.text("title");
  table.text("description");
  table.integer("rating");
  table.integer("user_id").references("id").inTable("users").onDelete("CASCADE");
  table.timestamp("created_at").default(knex.fn.now());
  table.timestamp("updated_at").default(knex.fn.now());
})

exports.down = knex => knex.schema.dropTable("movie_notes");
```

```
exports.up = knex => knex.schema.createTable("movie_tags", table => {
  table.increments("id");
  table.integer("movie_id").references("id").inTable("movie_notes").onDelete("CASCADE");
  table.integer("user_id").references("id").inTable("users").onDelete("CASCADE");
  table.text("name");
})

exports.down = knex => knex.schema.dropTable("movie_tags");
```

**MY PROBLEM:**

When I delete my notes, tags are also deleted (delete on cascade working very well), **BUT** when i delete a user who created notes and tags, these notes and tags aren't deleting (delete on cascade not working)

what can i do to fix it?

I expect delete all user notes and tags when i delete the user on database